# How to prove that approximating polynomials share a tangent line with approximated function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

We want approximate $\sqrt x$ in the point $(4,2)$. The Taylor polynomial centred in $x=4$:$$\frac{3}{4}+\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)x+\left(-\frac{1}{64}x^{2}\right)$$
Now we claim that this polynomial and $\sqrt x$ share a tangent line:
I writed that $$f(x) \geq f(c)+f'(c)(x-c)$$
So the $f(x)$ is above the graph of all tangent line for $0<c \leq 2$
But i cannot continue is some clever way, maybe there is some theorems that i don't know. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier if you keep the Taylor polynomial written in the form that shows where it's centred at, but even without doing that you can directly find tangent lines:

For $f(x)$, we have $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$ and so the tangent line at $(x_0, \sqrt{x_0})$ is $\frac{y - \sqrt{x_0}}{x - x_0} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x_0}}$ which becomes $y = \frac{x}{2 \sqrt{x_0}} + \frac{\sqrt{x_0}}{2}$. In particular, at $(4, 2)$ the tangent line is $y = \frac{x}{4} + 1$.

It is fairly easy to prove that the given Taylor polynomial has the exact same tangent line at that point.